# Find the angle of the plane makes with the semimeridian $\phi=\phi_0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

(doCarmo 2.5-2)Let (,)=(sincos,sinsin,cos)
be parametrization of the sphere $^2$
. Let 
be the plane =cot
, 0<<
and 
be the acute angle which the curve $∩^2$
makes with the semimeridian $$=$_0$
. Compute cos
.

I've followed hints from posts on the same question. But still not sure how to proceed after having $cot\alpha=tan\theta cot\alpha$ and $x_{\theta}$, $x_{\phi}$. I guess I'm supposed to find $\theta'$ and $\phi '$ but I'm not sure how.